# Citation needed for convergence of binomial series

Tags: reference-request

I am using some [results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series#Conditions_for_convergence) on the convergence of the (generalized) binomial series. Any idea on where to find it? More specifically, we need the proof of the point II, i.e. the convergence on the border of the domain.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't the proof just below of what you linked?